# Changes not persisted in database in a Spring Boot application using Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application that needs adds a post to a feed list. A post is written by a user and consists of a content and several attachments. The database has 3 tables: post, attachment and user.

The main class of the application is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SocialMediaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialMediaApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The entities are the following:

***Post.java***

```
@Entity
public class Post implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Timestamp createdAt;

    @Column
    private String location;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Attachment> attachmentList;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Rating> ratingList;

    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(String content, User user, Timestamp createdAt, String location, List<Attachment> attachmentList, List<Rating> ratingList) {
        super();
        this.content = content;
        this.user = user;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.location = location;
        this.attachmentList = attachmentList;
        this.ratingList = ratingList;
    }

    // ...
}
```

***Attachment.java***

```
@Entity
public class Attachment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Lob
    @Column(length = 100_000, nullable = false)
    private byte[] content;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Post post;

    public Attachment() {
    }

    public Attachment(byte[] content, Post post) {
        super();
        this.content = content;
        this.post = post;
    }

    // ...
}
```

***User.java***

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String credential;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String location;

    @Lob
    @Column(length = 100_000)
    private byte[] photo;

    @Column
    private String motto;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, Date dateOfBirth, String credential, String password,
            String location, byte[] photo, String motto) {
        super();
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.credential = credential;
        this.password = password;
        this.location = location;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.motto = motto;
    }

    // ...
}
```

All repositories extend CrudRepository and are annotated with @Transactional:

***PostRepository.java***

```
@Transactional
public interface PostRepository extends CrudRepository<Post, Long> {

}
```

***AttachmentRepository.java***

```
@Transactional
public interface AttachmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Attachment, Long> {

}
```

***UserRepository.java***

```
@Transactional
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

The controller that should add a post to the feed is the following:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/post")
public class PostController {

    @Autowired
    PostRepository postRepository;

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("post", new Post());
        return "addPost";
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addPost(@ModelAttribute Post post, @RequestParam("attachment") MultipartFile uploadingFile) throws IOException {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(1L);
        post.setUser(user);
        post.setCreatedAt(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        List<Attachment> attachmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.setContent(uploadingFile.getBytes());
        attachment.setPost(post);
        attachmentList.add(attachment);
        post.setAttachmentList(attachmentList);
        List<Rating> ratingList = new ArrayList<>();
        post.setRatingList(ratingList);
        postRepository.save(post);
        return "allPosts";
    }

}
```

The ***addPost.html*** page has the following content:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Add Post</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Add Post</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/post/add}" th:object="${post}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <table border="0">
      <tr>
       <td>Content</td>
       <td><textarea id="content" th:field="*{content}" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Location</td>
       <td><input type="text" id="location" th:field="*{location}"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>Attachment</td>
       <td><input type="file" id="attachment" name="attachment"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
       </td>
      </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The ***application.properties*** file has the following content:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/****?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=****
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings=false
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```

However, when I press the submit button, nothing is persisted into the database, although the queries are being displayed in the console:

```
Hibernate: insert into post (content, created_at, location, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into attachment (content, post_id) values (?, ?)
```

What could be the cause?

Comment: If you look at CrudRepository source code, there is no Transactional annotation for save() method. Your Transactional annotation does not apply to CrudRepository. You can declare save methods in your repositories, then Transactional annotation will take effect.

Comment: I did that, but the behavior is still the same, the information does not persist to the database :(

Comment: Not sure why it did not work. You probably need to introduce a new layer to initiate a transaction. For instance, create PostService class with Transaction anotation and call repository from it.